# Tasker: Wi-Fi On When I Turn Screen on in the Morning

Tags: tasker

I want to set up `Tasker` to **turn on my Wi-Fi** in the morning, when I **FIRST** **turn the screen on** that day **AFTER 7AM**.

I've managed to create the **Wi-Fi On** task and I assume I would also need to use the **Display On** event. This is my first time using `Tasker` so I'm unsure how to set it up to be triggered as mentioned.

**How do I setup the task mentioned above in `Tasker`?**

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide when the morning ends, but let's say this is between 7 - 9 am.

1. Create a profile that's active between 7 and 9 am. Also, this profile is ony active if Wifi-state is set to Off and if Display state is set to on.
2. Run the task "wifi on"-task you previously created.

Now when all the conditions in step one is true, the task will run.